# Android M Changes ART Runtime changes

Tags: android

My application targets `API level 21` , uses the both libraries `v7 appcompat library` and `v7 recyclerview` and in [Android M Changes doc](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-power) they says the following:

> The ART runtime now properly implements access rules for the newInstance() method. This change fixes a problem where Dalvik was checking access rules incorrectly in previous versions. If your app uses the newInstance() method and you want to override access checks, call the setAccessible() method with the input parameter set to true. If your app uses the v7 appcompat library or the v7 recyclerview library, you must update your app to use to the latest versions of these libraries. Otherwise, make sure that any custom classes referenced from XML are updated so that their class constructors are accessible.

I want to know what i shall to do because i didn't understand this sentence ? how this will affect my application ?

**I know this is a foolish question and i am a daft man but i need a help.

Comment: It seems an issue with classes that use reflection. And the advises about the libraries simply say that they may need to be updated for Android M. Do you use reflection?

Comment: Reflection on what ? reflection on this libraries (appcompat and recyclerview) ? and if i am targeting api lower than 23 shall i update those libraries ?

Comment: Reflection on your classes. If you use reflection in your app, you are responsible for updating your app. Google is responsible for updating appcompat and recycleview. Third parties are responsible for updating their libraries. **You are ultimately responsible to use/reference the updated libraries**. If you are not targeting Android M, why are you concerned with its compatibility in the first place?

Comment: In the documentation they says **If you have previously published an app for Android, be aware that these changes in the platform affect your app.** So i have to check if the app installed on Android M will work properly or not.

I mean if i use reflection on Android framework class or java class , what shall i update ?

Comment: With reflection you can access fields and methods even if they are inaccessible according to their modified (e.g. they are private) using things like `setAccessible`. If you are doing such things, beware that **previously** Dalvik didn't require a call to `setAccessible` while now it does.

Comment: -Then If my app uses reflection ,  targets **api level lower than 23** and is installed on device has android M then the reflection won't work properly and i must update the code ?
- Also I have to update (appcompat , recyclerview), however i target api level 21 ?

Comment: It's seem so. Better way to know: test it on an emulator/device with Android M.

Comment: It seems that they instantiating the items in xml with reflection and the updates to those APIs (appcompat , recyclerview) have fixed somethings related to reflection ?  and the old APIs will be affected with then new ART Runtime ?